# How can I tell when there are no solutions? Algorithm task

Tags: algorithm, search, math, game-theory

In a nutshell , given such a problem:

We load the number of players,

money each player,

and we load a string consisting of L i W

For example:

4 -> player's

2, 3, 2, 1

2 is a money a first player, 3 a second etc.

and we load cycle

for example:

WLL -> W == win = cash + 1, L == lost = cash -1;

If to one of the players runs out of money, interrupts the game giving the number of games all players.

So:

The cycle repeats itself, so, we have WLLWLL ... WLL

2, 3, 2, 1

[WLL - first cycle] [WLL - next cycle]

so, we have:

3,2,1,2

next:

2,1,2,1

And in the end:

1,2,1,0

And we count the number of games - 12

It is also the case when the players never lose , you then write -1

So,

my question is: How do I write a program that would calculate it as efficiently and if the game would never end wrote -1?

I have something like that:

```
enter code here

#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int n, m, ile_gier;
bool nieskonczonosc = true;
cin >> n;
int tab[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> tab[i];
}
cin >> m;
char znak[m];
cin >> znak;
int przesuniecie = n%m;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if(znak[i+przesuniecie] == 'W') nieskonczonosc = true;

}
if(nieskonczonosc == true) cout << "-1" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume you have n players and a cicle with length k and the money each player has is greater then the n.
Therefore the next row will be shifted by n mod k. now you can calculate the money change  after k rows (there the shift will definitely be 0) now you can calculate a state of the game and the number of rows where the game is nearly over (only if all changes after n rows are positive the game does not end) after that you can just calculate it straight forward.

PS You can improve this by taking n/gCd(n,k) rows because there the shift will be 0 as well. and you coould calculate the max Decrease of money in n rounds of all players. therefore the money of the player can get down to this value before you have to eval everything.....

Edit: Here is a sample code... it's not perfect, but you should be able to understand what I ment.....

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

int bruteforce(int nPlayer, int* money, const std::string,int,bool doesEnd);
void calculateWin(int nPlayer, const std::string Cycle, int* changes);
int fastforward(int nPlayer, int* money,int* changes);

int main()
{
    const int nPlayer = 4;
    int money[nPlayer] = { 5,5,5,5 };
    std::string Cycle = "WLL";

    int changes[nPlayer];

    calculateWin(nPlayer, Cycle, changes);

    bool doesEnd = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < nPlayer;i++)
        if (changes[i] < 0)
        {
            doesEnd = true;
            break;
        }



    if (doesEnd)
    {
        int fast = 0;
         fast = fastforward(nPlayer, money, changes);
        std::cout << "Games: " << fast*Cycle.length()*nPlayer+ bruteforce(nPlayer, money, Cycle, 0, 1) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        int games = bruteforce(nPlayer, money, Cycle, 0, 0);
        if (games == -1)
            std::cout << "The Game will not end" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Games: " << games<<std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");

}

int bruteforce(int nPlayer, int* money, const std::string Cycle, int offset,bool doesend)
{
    int nGames = 0;
    int player = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        player %= nPlayer;
        offset %= Cycle.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < nPlayer;i++)
            if (money[i] <= 0) return nGames;
        money[player] += Cycle[offset] == 'W' ? 1 : -1;
        player++;
        offset++;
        nGames++;
        if (!doesend&&nGames == nPlayer*Cycle.length())return -1;


    }
}


void calculateWin(int nPlayer, const std::string Cycle, int* changes) // calculates the changes after nPlayer*Cycle.length() Games
{
    int shift = nPlayer % Cycle.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < nPlayer;i++)
    {
        changes[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0;j < Cycle.length();j++)
            changes[i]+= Cycle[(j*shift+i)%Cycle.length()] == 'W'?1:-1;

    }
}

int fastforward(const int nPlayer, int* money, int* changes)
{

    int res = 2147483647; // max int 

    for (int i = 0; i < nPlayer;i++)
    {
        if(changes[i]<0)
            res = std::min( (money[i] - nPlayer) / -changes[i],res);
    }
    if (res < 0)
        return 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < nPlayer; i++)
        money[i] += res * changes[i]; 

    return res;
}
```

Comment: You could write it in a letter of steps?

Comment: My code doesen't work - I don't know why

Comment: Can you write this in c++?

Comment: How I can calculate it?

Comment: Look my code, what's next?